# Html Tag doesn't get render properly in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am loading  a html string in my UIWebView. Everything is working fine but when i tried to load a html containing <&reg > tag webview doesn't render it properly. Example if i have "Capital One® Secured" it is not rendering tag ® simplay display it as it is on the webview. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to enclose `&reg` in tag marks. Instead, you should use `&reg;` by itself where you want the registered trademark symbol.

E.g.

```
NSString *HTMLString = @"<p>Capital One&reg; Secured</p>";
[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLString baseURL:nil];
```